# How do I modify and later save GRIB files in python keeping the original extension .grb?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, python-xarray, grib, cfgrib

What I already did is reading (with xarray and cfgrib) the file GRIB (.grb) and replacing some of its values. So I did actually already managed to access and modify the file. What I'm not able to do is to "save the changes", so to save this new modified file as GRIB. I can save it as netcdf but that's not my goal.
Here's what I've already tried:

```
# I used this to open the file:
fileGRIB = xr.open_dataset('file_path', engine = 'cfgrib')
# I applied some small changes values(of precipitation in this file case)
[...]
# And I tried to save the file back to GRIB:
cfgrib.to_grib(fileGRIB, 'output.grib')
fileGRIB.to_netcdf('output.grb', engine = 'cfgrib')
```

These last commands didn't work:

- to_netcdf gave me an 'unrecognized engine' error
- cfgrib.to_grib gave me 'KeyError: 830912400000000000'

Comment: What you need is grib_tables for the unknown keys.

Comment: Sorry @dl.meteo , I'm actually new to GRIB files. How do I get these grib_tables I need?

Comment: Normally from the weather service who published the grib file or you define them by yourself but I recommend to ask the publisher of the data. WMO requires NWS to provide their grib tables.